# Counting specific words using def function and defaultdict

Tags: python

I'm having issues with my code below. I'm trying to create a function that will create a count of headlines with specified words (see below); but I keep getting an error "unhashable type: 'list'".

rlist is a LIST but how else should I use the defaultdict method? My *args is "the", "and", and "cat".

```
''' 
  create a function that will 
  create a count of headlines with specified words 
  rlist: the list of headlines in the list of lists format
  args: words to search for
  return: a dictionary of each specified word and its count
'''

def wordcount(rlist, *args):
    word_count = defaultdict(int)
    for headline in rlist:
        word_count[headline] += 1
        
    return word_count(args)

print(wordcount(y2006_headline_lists, "the", "and", "cat"))
```

Comment: I get a different error. Your `return word_count(args)` is wrong. You can't call `word_count` since it is a `dict`. In any case, `word_count[args]` will just return `0`. Perhaps you want to do `return {k: word_count[k] for k in args}`.

Comment: It's because `rlist` is a list of lists. So `headline` is a list, and therefore you can't do `word_count[headline]`, because lists are mutable objects

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that headline is a list of single word strings this should be able to fix your issue. You just need to iterate over headlines and update word_count. Then if you are only interested in returning the counts for args use dict comprehension to filter out rest.

```
from collections import defaultdict

y2006_headline_lists = [
    ["the", "soldier", "returned"],
    ["I", "and", "the", "cat"],
    ["cat", "in", "the", "hat"],
]


def wordcount(rlist, *args):
    word_count = defaultdict(int)
    for headlines in rlist:
        for headline in headlines:
            word_count[headline] += 1

    word_count = {arg: word_count[arg] for arg in args}
    return word_count


print(wordcount(y2006_headline_lists, "the", "and", "cat"))
```